# Start Alfresco Workflow on outside Alfresco Content

Tags: workflow, alfresco

I am newbie in Alfresco. I was just going through the Alfresco documents [here](http://docs.alfresco.com/community5.0/concepts/mytasks.html). I have gone through it, but didn't get the answer of my question as described below.

> Is it possible to start workflow(/task) on the content outside of the Alfresco Content (i.e. Our Local System File/Folder)?  If yes, how can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Younes that you can configure a rule to launch a workflow. In order to do that, you'll want to take a look at the [JavaScript workflow API](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/API-JS-WorkflowService.html).

Using a rule on a folder will require something to trigger the rule, such as a document being added to the folder. But your question asks if a workflow can be triggered *external* to Alfresco. To do that, you might consider using a [Web Script](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/dev-extension-points-webscripts.html).

A Web Script is simply a way to extend Alfresco's RESTful API with your own logic. So you could create a web script called "startMyWorkflow" that includes a JavaScript controller leveraging the same API I referenced earlier to kick off the workflow. With that in place, you'd be able to launch the workflow externally using anything that can speak REST over HTTP.

Comment: @JeffPotts I may have forgotten to mention that -as the op suggested- he could then setup a cifs/ftp/webdav folder locally to point to some location in the repo having that rule action I was talking about.... So for example adding files to that folder would automatically start a workflow....

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a rule action to start a workflow if certain conditions are met (files added to some folder, file metadata changed, a new revision has been uploaded ...).

To learn how to create new rules in alfresco follow [this tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/actions/tutorial/tutorial.html)

---

**Update :** I may have forgotten to mention that -as the op suggested- he could then setup a cifs/ftp/webdav folder locally to point to some location in the repo having that rule action I was talking about.... So for example adding files to that folder would automatically start a workflow....